# Android :How to define dialog fragment that is accessed by multiple activities?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have an Activity1 that shows a custom dialogfragment- ExampleDialog. I have implemented a listener, SubmitDialogListener for the dialogfragment to communicate with the activity using onSubmit(). In onSubmit(), I am showing some other dialogfragment. My question is, if I show the same ExampleDialog Fragment from Activity2, should Activity2 implement the SubmitDialogListener interface and implement the onSubmit() method in Activity2 again? Or is there a better way to define the onSubmit() method?

```
import android.support.v4.app.DialogFragment;
// ...   
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  ......
  showDialog();
}

private void showDialog() {
  FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
  ExampleDialog exDialog = ExampleDialog.newInstance("Some Title");
  exDialog.show(fm, "fragment_edit_name");
}

@Override
public void onSubmit() {
//open new fragments
}
}

public class ExampleDialog extends DialogFragment implements SubmitDialogListener {

public interface SubmitDialogListener {
    void onSubmit();
}

public ExampleDialog() {
    // Empty constructor required for DialogFragment
}

public static ExampleDialog newInstance(String title) {
    ExampleDialog frag = new ExampleDialog();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString("title", title);
    frag.setArguments(args);
    return frag;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_edit_name, container);
    .........

   Button button = (Button) v.findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

         SubmitDialogListener listener = (SubmitDialogListener) getActivity();
        listener.onSubmit();
        dismiss();
        }
    });

    return view;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case the Activity should implement the `SubmitDialogListener` not the Dialog Fragment, like this:

```
public class Activity1 extends ActionBarActivity implements SubmitDialogListener {

  @Override 
  public void onSubmit() { 
    //open new fragments 
  }
}
```

And if you want to use the same dialog fragment in multiple activities, it's generally best to create it in a separate class file.